# working on a forked repo for github on a feature branch where I was completing some work

Tags: git, github

In between me completing the work they updated the upstream project.
On my local master branch for the project, I added the upstream and pulled from it.
On github it says that my project is even with the remote master.
When I tried to merge my feature branch I got an error generated from github itself that there is a conflict with the remote repo that couldn't be fixed.
This next part is what I need help with.
From the feature branch I merged in the master which I now know is wrong. But at the time it let me create a PR with the project. I noticed under commits that it had all the previous updates as work I had completed. I have since gone back and tried to do a rebase to my local master but it is giving me this error:

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in package.json
```

Is this something that I can manually update on the feature branch to make it match or what should my next step be?

Thank you!

Comment: Merge conflicts are okay, and normal. When this message appears, open the file in a text editor and correct the contents to be what you expect (an easy solution, copy it from the correct source branch in github). Then stage and commit the file in git.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the quick response. I will get that issue resolved.
So for the number of commits that I have pushed to the repo, I should just squash them and resolve the conflicts as I encounter them?